# Solve $x^4+24x^3+18x^2−27=0$.

Tags: functions

> Solve $x^4+24x^3+18x^2−27=0$.

The answer is quite good looking (for a quartic equation), I don't know much idea. Maybe somebody may give my a bit clue? Thanks.

Comment: Substitute $y=x+6$

Comment: You only get one root in $(0,1)$ and one in $(-24,-23)$ on the reals, no good-looking either...

Comment: @AlexR Only one real root? If it were so it would be a double root (which it isn't).

Comment: I think it's not quite looking: $x_{1,2}=-6-3\sqrt 3 \pm \sqrt{6(12+7\sqrt{3})}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's good to check first for rational zeroes and according to Rational Root Theorem if an rational number is zero of this function then it'll divide $27$. Unfortunally none of the divisors of $27$, nor positive, nor negative are solution. To solve it by pen and paper, you can use resolvents, so you'll reduce the equation to cubic equation and there will be a relation between the roots of the cubic with the roots of the quartic equation.

If you want to go "old-school" then use [Ferrari's Method](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Ferrari%27s_Method) to reduce the equation to cubic equation and the use [Cardano's method](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Cardano%27s_Formula) to reduce it to quadratic equation, which is rather simply to solve. But to do that by hand, you'll probably need half an hour of work, 3-4 sheets of paper and patience, because this method is very error-prone and complex solutions can be a problem. If you find one solution things become easier, because you can factorize and get cubic equation.